# Should an answer contain a SSCCE

Tags: discussion, answers

When answering a question today on SO, I was asked for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I know it is good practice to have a question with an SSCCE, but how about answers?

As far as I know, an answer doesn't have to provide a complete implementation for a given problem, but at least it should tell how to solve it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In my opinion, "Can I have an SSCCE" is just a nice form of saying "gimme the codez". It depends on the question and the answer if an example should be added (ideally a user would tell you what's unclear, so that you can edit it into your answer).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that for many developers, SO and similar sites are the only chance they have of seeing good code. Sad as it sounds, it's true: they are stuck maintaining crappy code, they don't have time/resources/possiblity/drive to actively learn outside their job and the only time they see code from someone else is on SO or on forums. And if *that code always* has `catch` blocks that are empty, then they'll think that's normal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't verified this statistically, but I would say that my answers are about evenly split—I provide sample code about half of the time, the rest of the time I provide *just* the explanation.

It depends on a lot of factors, like how much time I have when composing the answer, how easy/straightforward I think it is to write the necessary code, and the quality of the original question.

Sometimes I feel strongly about *not* including a self-contained example; for example, instances where I think it's more important to teach people to fish, rather than including ready-to-go code. Too often, the "example" code gets copied and pasted into production code, which is *never* appropriate. Even if you do like [Joachim suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188960/153008) and post production-ready sample code (and really, who does that?) with error handling and all that jazz, it's still not okay because the person pasting the code doesn't understand how it works. I can't imagine many things scarier than having code checked into one of my projects that no one on the team understands how it works. What's going to happen when it is discovered to contain a bug, or it inevitably breaks under some condition or after an upgrade—who's going to maintain it? How am I going to know if/how it will interact with the rest of my code, and make modifications if necessary? Not to mention the security vulnerabilities of mystery code pasted in from an unknown source.

If I think "copy-paste" programming is imminent, or I think it's a homework-style question, I'll omit the example. The answer already gives them everything they need (or so is my intent) to write the code themselves, once they take the time to read and understand what it says. And that's way more helpful. If the code isn't even there in ready-to-go form, they can't miss the explanation and any important caveats that I may have mentioned.

Or maybe it's just my personal protest against this becoming a "give-me-teh-codez" website.

So, in sum: no, I don't think a good answer is required to contain a self-contained example. A good answer *can* contain one, but it is supplementary only. Conversely, an answer that contains *only* an example is not a good answer. An explanation of *how* the code works is an absolutely necessary component; a demonstration can be a nice addition but is not essential. **If any competent (and/or sufficiently motivated) developer can put together the pieces and write whatever code is necessary, then you've got a complete answer.**

That said, if someone asks nicely and is informed enough to ask for a SSCCE, I would probably relent and update my answer to include one.

Comment: The most important sentence in this answer is _"Conversely, an answer that contains only an example is not a good answer."_. It might also be the most important sentence on MSO...

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion: it's a nice-to-have. You can have a perfectly fine answer without one, but an answer *with* an SSCCE will probably get more upvotes.

My plea: **if** you post a SSCCE in an answer, make sure <s>it's production-quality (no empty catch-blocks, sane error handling, ...)</s> it doesn't glance over important aspects such as error-handling, possibly logging, input validation, edge conditions, etc. Those things end up as-is in production code more often than not.

And something to keep in mind: sometimes the error handling, behaviour in corner cases and how well your code handles unexpected strangeness is the difference between acceptable code and great code.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your plea. Naturally there should be no abominations like empty catch-blocks or SQL injection vulnerabilities. But I'm not convinced that samples should be truly production-quality in terms of error handling. The *real* production-quality code that I write is sometimes so cluttered with error handling that the actual solution to the problem would be rather buried. I usually omit *all* error handling unless it's germane to the question being asked, leaving that as an exercise to the user.

Comment: Clear answer... but it leaves me wondering, whether its  responsibility of the person who answers a question when the person who asked it chooses to copy-paste example code (sometimes even including comments like "Do error handling here") to production code. How about that?

Comment: @mthmulders: no, it's definitely *not* their responsibility. Those who blindly copy-and-paste solutions are definitely to blame. But the problem is that they are not the only ones who suffer from them. Chances are their colleagues that are still with the company 3 years later have to deal with it. And personally I'd like to make *their* lifes a bittle better

Comment: @CodyGray: well, I agree that my view might not be the most popular one. Feel free to post another answer and let the votes decide ;-)

Comment: Why on earth should it be "production quality"? Depending on the application adding error handling etc may well bury the answer in a load of unnecessary code.

Comment: @ChrisF: I think "production quality" is a bad chosen (and explained) term here. Generally I'd say "yes, code on SO should be production quality...no, code here does not need to be production ready".

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - I disagree. Why would you need to see all the error handling code in a question when I've shown you the five lines that produce the error? How I handle the error is irrelevant. The problem is that the error is occurring. The same applies to code in an answer. Here's the fix that will stop *this* **unexpected** error, how you handle the other **expected** errors is up to you.

Comment: @ChrisF: Let me rephrase, that was exactly what I wanted to say. With "production quality" code I meant code which f.e. does not store plaintext passwords, or sends unchecked queries to the database, or fails the moment you hand it a number higher then 5 without an explanation why. In this case I meant "production quality = code that can be used in production" compared to "production ready = C&P and you're ready to go". So I agree with you, implementing error handling does nothing here, but there should be a comment (in the code or outside) telling you what problems may arise (if not obvious).

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on the kind of question you're answering, and whether examples will likely be found in readily available documentation. Don't give askers the idea that it's easier to find an example by posting a basic question here rather than reading the documentation or (*shudder*) their textbook:

- If you're teaching a tricky bit of C++ syntax: good.
- If you're teaching how to write a `for` loop in Java: not so good.
- Nonobvious use of complex API: good
- Basic use of a simple API: not so good.