# Politely refusing to provide a laborious implementation of my detailed algorithmic answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, time

A user asked for a complex algorithm. I [answered in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780731/get-previous-gyroscope-coordinates/21170300#21170300), which took me some time. The user then mentioned (politely) in a comment that he would like me to provide code. Writing the code would take me a few weeks of work.

What's the etiquette to explain to the user that while I did answer the question I am not going to do his/her job?

Comment: I believe this question is not a duplicate with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190025/what-is-the-etiquette-for-backing-away-from-a-question. I believe my question is about me not having the time to answer, while the linked question is about whether it would be beneficial to the person who asked the question to receive an answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Sounds like this question is either a chameleon-questions if it keeps changing, or way **way** too broad if not

Comment: Could you link to the question as an example

Comment: I guess we're talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780731/get-previous-gyroscope-coordinates/21170300#21170300?

Comment: Indeed Duncan, thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried to edit that question to tidy the grammar and got thoroughly lost. I can't understand what is being asked at all. Since you obviously do understand it, could you please try editing the question for clarity? It would put your answer in better context

Comment: Frankly I think you've gone above and beyond the call of duty as it is

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: I gave an off-topic answer before figuring out what the actual question was :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't you have to be overly polite. In this case, I've [done the dirty work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780731/get-previous-gyroscope-coordinates/21170300#comment31899430_21170300) and given you an up-vote (hurray!) and added a close vote to the question (*wayyyy* too broad).

In future, don't feel bad about adding a similar comment yourself. There are some people out there who'd love it if the community wrote all their code for them! Had the OP asked a more specific question, it might have prompted you to supply code. But he didn't, so you didn't!

---

Note: [rene has shared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216534/what-is-the-etiquette-when-a-user-asks-for-time-consuming-questions-after-an-alr/216536#comment701150_216534) a very polite way of saying the same thing. I quite like his wording:

> It is much more fun and a great learning expierence to try your self. I sketched the outline, you fill in the blanks. Feel free to ask a new question if you run into trouble with your code, I'm sure other members are prepared to help you with the small steps towards your end goal, good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot.